# Dependency problem tkinter

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm, dependencies, oracle-linux

I am trying to install a package, specifically tkinter-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64.rpm, on Oracle Linux 7. I run into a dependency problem:

```
Error: Package: tkinter-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64 (/tkinter-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: python = 2.7.5-86.el7
           Installed: python-2.7.5-86.0.3.el7.x86_64 (@ol7_latest/7.6)
               python = 2.7.5-86.0.3.el7
```

Appears I am running a newer version than what the package wants. Whats the approach to resolve the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two options: downgrade python and rebuild tkinter from source. (technically five but since you really want to install tkinter, you want be happy with either not installing it or blowing up the computer, and overriding dependencies is an ugly ball of wax with extra cat hair.)

A quick google search for either option should find multiple examples and walkthroughs. Pick one you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter dependency is on extraordinary stage than these of pip-installable packages. I'm not aware of any means for apt-get deploy -ing through pip.

On the other hand, if you have a Debian based distro, you can apt-get deploy thonny, which installs all requirements, together with python3-tk.